# How to determine whether a checkbox is checked or not in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

Default.aspx;

```
        <form id="form1" runat="server" action="Default2.aspx" method="post">
          <input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change"/> 
        </form>
```

Default2.aspx.cs

```
     string ismultiple = Request.Form["change"].ToString();
     Response.Write(ismultiple);
```

how to determine whether checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is checked you get as return the

```
   bool fIsChecked = Request.Form["change"] == "checked";
```

Comment: i dont want it to make checked by default

Comment: @prerna ok, I just add it, is the first that you need

Comment: ii have tried this this is always returning false whether checked or unchecked

Comment: @prerna On Post back ? i do not think so.

Comment: @prerna Do not complicate your self, make a post back and a break point there and see whats value return to you. I do not see in this form a submit button. Are you make post back or wait to see what is happening by just click on it ?

Comment: i am doing this in postback only

Comment: @prerna Ok, make a break point there and see what return. See and the full Request.Form (on debug.)